# Regarding display of icons in tinymce editor

Tags: css, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a plugin in which I am using  the tinymce editor for generating reports. The icons of the editor are displaying correctly in local system but not displaying correctly in the production server. Any solution on this would be a great help.

Thanking you

[image]

Comment: Maybe it will helps you: [Github issues](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/issues/65)

Comment: Strategy: look at the src attribute of images, or if it's done with css, the uri used for the background property of the divs etc.  Copy the address into your browser in a new tab.  Is the file there?